# Python Status Bar

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am having a problem with adding status bar at the bottom of my program. When I do status.pack() it gives me this error : _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack. In My (
def **init**(self): ) If I delete (self.grid(sticky = W+E+N+S) then the window pops up an then the status bar is on the window, but then the rest of the program isn't there. I was wondering if someone give some insight on how to fix this

```
from tkinter.constants import END
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk
import turtle 
import random
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image

class App(Frame):
```

## **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************8888

```
'''The code below Creates a Menu Bar across the top of the window '''    
App = Tk()
menu = Menu (App)
App.config(menu = menu)  
'''Lines 20 - 22 are basic setup for drop down meun box at the top of the page.'''


fileMenu = Menu(menu, tearoff = 0)
fileMenu.add_command(label = "New Project", command = turtle)
fileMenu.add_command(label = "Open", command = turtle)
fileMenu.add_command(label = "Save", command = turtle)
fileMenu.add_command(label = "Save as", command = turtle)
fileMenu.add_command(label = "Close", command = turtle)
menu.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = fileMenu)

fileMenu.add_separator() 
'''This bit of code adds a separator between the buttons on the drop down menu.'''
fileMenu.add_command(label = "Exit", command = App.quit)

editMenu = Menu(menu, tearoff = 0)
editMenu.add_command(label = "Cut", command = turtle)
editMenu.add_command(label = "Copy", command = turtle)
editMenu.add_command(label = "Paste", command = turtle)
editMenu.add_command(label = "Delete", command = turtle)
editMenu.add_command(label = "Select All", command = turtle)
menu.add_cascade(label = "Edit", menu = editMenu)

helpMenu = Menu(menu, tearoff = 0)
helpMenu.add_command(label = "Help Index", command = turtle)
helpMenu.add_command(label = "About", command = turtle)
menu.add_cascade(label = "Help", menu = helpMenu)
```

## ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

```
''' The code below creates a Status Bar Across the bottom of the page. '''

status = Label(App, text = "This is a status bar...", bd = 1, relief = SUNKEN, anchor = W)
status.pack()
```

## ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

```
def __init__(self):
    '''Sets up the window and widgets.'''
    Frame.__init__(self, bg = "white" ) #this sets the background color of the window.
    self.master.title("Auto Body Buddy Estimator")  #this is the title of the screen
    self.master.geometry("600x600") #this is the specs for the window size
    self.master.resizable(0, 0)     #this makes the window none resizable
    self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    self.grid(sticky = W+E+N+S)

    #!/usr/bin/python

    '''import cgi, os
    import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

    form = cgi.FieldStorage()

    # Get filename here.
    fileitem = form['filename']

    # Test if the file was uploaded
    if fileitem.filename:
        # strip leading path from file name to avoid 
        # directory traversal attacks
        fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
        open('/tmp/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())

        message = ('The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully')

    else:
        message = 'No file was uploaded'

        print """\
        Content-Type: text/html\n
        <html>
        <body>
           <p>%s</p>
        </body>
        </html>
        """ % (message,) '''
```

## ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

```
    ''' Creates the nested frame for the Data pane for the image '''
    self._dataPane1 = Frame(self)#, bg = "orange")
    self._dataPane1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    self._pictureImage = PhotoImage(file = "../logo.gif")
    self._imageLabel = Label(self._dataPane1, image = self._pictureImage)
    self._imageLabel.grid(row = 0, column= 0)
```

## *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

```
    ''' Creates the nested frame for the Data pane'''
    self._dataPaneEntryInfo = Frame(self, bg = "white")
    self._dataPaneEntryInfo.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

    ''' Label and field for First Name '''
    self._firstNameLabel = Label(self._dataPaneEntryInfo, bg = "white", text = "First Name ")
    self._firstNameLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    self._firstNameVar = DoubleVar()
    self._firstNameEntry = Entry(self._dataPaneEntryInfo, textvariable = self._firstNameVar)
    self._firstNameEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    ''' Label and field for Last Name '''
    self._LastNameLabel = Label(self._dataPaneEntryInfo, bg = "white", text = "Last Name ")
    self._LastNameLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    self._LastNameVar = DoubleVar()
    self._LastNameEntry = Entry(self._dataPaneEntryInfo, textvariable = self._LastNameVar)
    self._LastNameEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    ''' Label and field for Phone Number '''
    self._phoneNumberLabel = Label(self._dataPaneEntryInfo, bg = "white", text = "Phone Number ")
    self._phoneNumberLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    self._phoneNumberVar = DoubleVar()
    self._phoneNumberEntry = Entry(self._dataPaneEntryInfo, textvariable = self._phoneNumberVar)
    self._phoneNumberEntry.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

    ''' Label and field for Email '''
    self._EmailLabel = Label(self._dataPaneEntryInfo, bg = "white", text = "Email Address ")
    self._EmailLabel.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
    self._EmailVar = DoubleVar()
    self._EmailEntry = Entry(self._dataPaneEntryInfo, textvariable = self._EmailVar)
    self._EmailEntry.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

    ''' Label and field for Address '''
    self._addressLabel = Label(self._dataPaneEntryInfo, bg = "white", text = "Address \n (OPITIONAL) ")
    self._addressLabel.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
    self._addressVar = DoubleVar()
    self._addressEntry = Entry(self._dataPaneEntryInfo, textvariable = self._addressVar)
    self._addressEntry.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
```

## *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

```
    ''' Label and field for Year of the Car '''
    self._yearLabel = Label(self._dataPaneEntryInfo, bg = "white", text = "Year ")
    self._yearLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
    self._yearVar = DoubleVar()
    self._yearEntry = Entry(self._dataPaneEntryInfo, textvariable = self._yearVar)
    self._yearEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 3)

    ''' Label and field for Make of the Car '''
    self._makeLabel = Label(self._dataPaneEntryInfo, bg = "white", text = "Make ")
    self._makeLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
    self._makeVar = DoubleVar()
    self._makeEntry = Entry(self._dataPaneEntryInfo, textvariable = self._makeVar)
    self._makeEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

    ''' Label and field for Model of the Car '''
    self._modelLabel = Label(self._dataPaneEntryInfo, bg = "white", text = "Model ")
    self._modelLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
    self._modelVar = DoubleVar()
    self._modelEntry = Entry(self._dataPaneEntryInfo, textvariable = self._modelVar)
    self._modelEntry.grid(row = 2, column = 3)

    ''' Label and field for Package of the Car '''
    self._packageLabel = Label(self._dataPaneEntryInfo, bg = "white", text = "Package ")
    self._packageLabel.grid(row = 3, column = 2)
    self._packageVar = DoubleVar()
    self._packageEntry = Entry(self._dataPaneEntryInfo, textvariable = self._packageVar)
    self._packageEntry.grid(row = 3, column = 3)

    ''' Label and field for VIN # of the Car '''
    self._vinLabel = Label(self._dataPaneEntryInfo, bg = "white", text = "VIN # ")
    self._vinLabel.grid(row = 4, column = 2)
    self._vinVar = DoubleVar()
    self._vinEntry = Entry(self._dataPaneEntryInfo, textvariable = self._vinVar)
    self._vinEntry.grid(row = 4, column = 3)
```

## ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

```
    ''' Creates the nested frame for the Data pane'''
    self._dataPaneComment = Frame(self, bg = "black")
    self._dataPaneComment.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

    '''# Label and info field for Comment Box .'''
    self._text = "Enter text here. "
    self._outputArea = Text(self._dataPaneComment, width = 50, height = 10, wrap = WORD)
    self._outputArea.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
```

## *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

```
    ''' Creates the nested frame for the Button pane for the Submit'''
    self._buttonPane = Frame(self) #this creates a box for the buttons to be placed in one area.
    self._buttonPane.grid(row = 3, column = 0)#this gives the button pane a position in the GUI

    ''' Black and White button '''
    self._button1 = Button(self._buttonPane, text = "SUBMIT", command = self._NameEntry)#This creates the button.
    self._button1.grid(row = 0, column = 0) #This gives the button a position in the GUI.
```

## ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

```
def _NameEntry(self):
    open("Results.txt", "w").close()

    first = self._firstNameEntry.get()
    last = self._LastNameEntry.get()
    phone = self._phoneNumberEntry.get()
    email = self._EmailEntry.get()
    address = self._addressEntry.get()
    year = self._yearEntry.get()
    make = self._makeEntry.get()
    model = self._modelEntry.get()
    package = self._packageEntry.get()
    vin = self._vinEntry.get()


    with open("../" + first + " " + last + ".txt", "a") as the_file:
        the_file.write("First Name: " + first + "\n" "Last Name: " + last + "\n" "Phone Number: " + phone + "\n" "Email: " + email + "\n" 
                       "Address: " + address + "\n" "Year: " + year + "\n" "Make: " + make + "\n" "Model: " + model + "\n" 
                       "Package: " + package + "\n" "Vin: " + vin + "\n")

    '''open("Results.txt", "w").close()
    last = self._LastNameEntry.get()
    with open("../Results.txt", "a") as the_file:
        the_file.write("Last Name: " + last)'''    

    '''first = self._firstNameEntry.get()   
    name = open("Results.txt", "w")
    name.write("First Name: ".insert(first))
    name.close()'''


def main():
'''Instantiate and pop up the window.'''

App().mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

I'm exactly sure on how to upload the gif file with this code.

Comment: Do you _really_ need all that code to duplicate this problem? You can probably duplicate it with about five lines of code. The root of the problem is just as the error says: you can't use both `grid` and `pack` for widgets in the same parent. Use one or the other.

Comment: I have tried using one or the other still has the same out come.

Comment: That's a ton of code to dig through, but I'd imagine that you have the same problem in other places as well. It's the only way you're getting this error.

Comment: regardless, the solution is to use one or the other for all widgets that share the same parent. Unfortunately you've pasted way too much code to sift through, plus the formatting is all screwed up. We can't debug all of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is telling you what's wrong. If you have already used one geometry manager within a widget you cannot use another.

e.g. - You cannot use both pack and grid within a frame. You must use one or the other.

You could make another widget and then use the seperate geometry manager within this widget but you would have to use the original manager to place it within the master widget.